# Runing Count with rest condition on another row consecutively

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe where I want to keep on increasing the value until `val` changes and when `id` changes reset the `count` value

```
data = [['p1','1'],
        ['p1','1'],
        ['p1','2'],
        ['p2','3'],
        ['p2','5'],
        ['p3','2'],
        ['p2','3'],
        ['p2','4']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','val'])
```

Desired output

```
   id val  count
0  p1   1      1
1  p1   1      1
2  p1   2      2
3  p2   3      1
4  p2   5      2
5  p3   2      1
6  p2   3      1
7  p2   4      2
```

When I am doing groupby than transform

```
df['count']=df.groupby('id').val.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
```

if you see the output only problem is the last row you will see count 3 as it is group by it is summing with the previous p2 but i want to ignore that and let reset completely and count increment consecutively rather than whole groupby.

```
   id val  count
0  p1   1      1
1  p1   1      1
2  p1   2      2
3  p2   3      1
4  p2   5      2
5  p3   2      1
6  p2   3      1
7  p2   4      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom Series created by compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
g = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()
df['count']=df.groupby(g).val.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)

print (df)
   id val  count
0  p1   1      1
1  p1   1      1
2  p1   2      2
3  p2   3      1
4  p2   5      2
5  p3   2      1
6  p2   3      1
7  p2   4      2
```